# Cant Login Admin in Opencart V 1.5.5.1

Tags: php, session, redirect, opencart

I just add some sub menu in admin page, so I change in admin page(controller,view,model,language,dll) and it's working in `local` (no error/problem in front/back end).

After that I upload to my website, when I try login in admin, it's stuck in http://website/admin/index.php?route=common/login with white blank page. In my **firebug** only have 1 error like this :

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

I check from internet it's write need code `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` in `head`, but I already use it in admin\view\template\common\header.tpl (this page is first opened)

If I refresh, it's back to login admin page. So I try check in my folder : admin\controller\common\login.php, actually I never change/edit this file in `localhost`.

And I found something wierd in this code Controller:

```
public function index() { 
    $this->language->load('common/login');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    if ($this->user->isLogged() && isset($this->request->get['token']) && ($this->request->get['token'] == $this->session->data['token'])) {
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
    }

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        $this->session->data['token'] = md5(mt_rand());
        if (isset($this->request->post['redirect'])) {
                //echo "INSIDE";exit;
                //echo $this->session->data['token'];
                //$this->redirect($this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));

            //THIS CODE WIERD
            $this->redirect($this->request->post['redirect'] . '&token=' . $this->session->data['token']);


        } else {
            echo "SECOND INSIDE";exit;
            $this->redirect($this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
        }
    }
    echo "OUTSIDE";exit;
```

I already try echo in outside/ inside if(make sure it's valid in validation) and it's `INSIDE`

This should be redirect page to home :(in local working)

```
$this->redirect($this->request->post['redirect'] . '&token=' . $this->session->data['token']);
```

But it's not work, like not executed ?? I try change code with redirect page like this :(working in local)

`$this->redirect($this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));`

I try write `echo "HOME";exit;` in `controller/common/home (index)` but nothing happen (it's mean not in direct to common/home).

And results still same like before stuck in http://website/admin/index.php?route=common/login. with white blank page.

**BUT** if I try write in `href` using session it's working normal

example `echo $this->session->data['token']; =  d899065aa6989387feaf82691506dec5`

http://website/admin/index.php?route=common/home&token=d899065aa6989387feaf82691506dec5

Anyone know where the problem come from? Or have experience like this? (sorry, has recently using OpenCart).